# react-redux, onClick does not launch action function(undefined)

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to make ajax request with react-redux on button pressed but got an error when onClick action tries to launch function from action component.

post_data.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import getPostsData from '../actions/index';

class PostButton extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.GetPostData = this.GetPostData.bind(this);
}

GetPostData(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.getPostsData();  
} 

render(){
    return(
        <div style={{marginTop: 50 + 'px'}}>
                <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.GetPostData}>Click Here to Load Posts</button>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({getPostsData}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostButton);
```

Action:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const GET_POSTS_DATA = 'GET_POSTS_DATA';

export function getPostsData() {
   const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`;

   const request = axios.get(url);
   console.log(request);

   return{
      type: GET_POSTS_DATA,
      payload: request
   }
}
```

Reducer:

```
 import GET_POSTS_DATA from '../actions/index';

 export default function(state = [], action){
    switch (action.type){

      case GET_POSTS_DATA:
        return [action.payload, ...state]
    }

    return state;
 }
```

Console error:
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.getPostsData is not a function
this is related to:

```
GetPostData(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.getPostsData();  
}
```

any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getPostsData import statement should be:

```
import {getPostsData} from '../actions/index';
```

The syntax you're using refers to the default export, from what I can tell in your snippet there is no default export.

Comment: Thank you, Nick!:) I knew it was something stupid and it is:)))) works as magic after I imported correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a typo: `getPostsData` is not a property of your `PostButton` component but an import from a js module.

Call directly `getPostsData()` in place of `this.props.getPostsData()`.

Comment: no, it should be a part of this.props but for some reason it is not... anyway, direct call also not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to call the mentioned function in your case:

```
GetPostData(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   getPostsData();  
}
```